# HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream blocking UI thread

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

First of all, I'm quite new to C# and .NET Framework in general, but what I'm trying to achieve is a (IMHO quite) simple goal, and yet I'm still encountering some trouble.

My goal is to use the `WebRequest` class to POST data to a web service. I've read through the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx) and examples, and in particular this part:

> The BeginGetRequestStream method requires some synchronous setup tasks
>   to complete (DNS resolution, proxy detection, and TCP socket
>   connection, for example) before this method becomes asynchronous. As a
>   result, this method should never be called on a user interface (UI)
>   thread because it might take some time, typically several seconds.

With reference to the linked example, how can I make the methods `GetRequestStreamCallback` and `GetResponseCallback` run in a background thread?

This is what I got so far:

```
private void startTask()
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
            worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            updateStatus(e.ProgressPercentage);
        }

        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            postData = /* data to be posted */;
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
            request.Method = "POST";

            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
        }

        private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;

            using (Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
            {
                stream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData).Length);
                stream.Close();
            }

            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
        }

        private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
        }
```

The reason I've used a `BackgroundWorker` is to interact with UI, but I'm opened to alternative solutions. My question is: does the worker terminate when execution flow reaches the end of the `worker_DoWork` function? Or even the callback functions are executed by the worker itself? And if not, is there an alternative to make this whole code run in a separate thread?

I apologize for the (probably) stupid question, but as I said, I'm quite new to .NET, and I still don't grasp the concept of threading and thread pools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BackgroundWorker thread completes at the end of the DoWork function, and then raises the RunWorkerCompleted on the thread that started the BackgroundWorker.

In your example, the GetResponseCallback will run on a different thread, since the thread that called request.BeginGetRequestStream will return to the pool at the end of DoWork.

To make it simple- you can use the synchronous version or the request/response methods (e.g. request.GetRequestStream) since you aren't on the UI thread anymore. Your UI thread can listen to RunWorkedCompleted to get the results of call from within the UI thread.

Comment: This is exactly the first solution that crossed my mind. Thanks for confirming it. But, just out of curiosity, is there any way to run callback functions in the same thread of the function that linked them to the event (in this case the worker_DoWork and GetRequestStreamCallback, maybe using some sort of wait in the worker_DoWork)?

Comment: One way would be to use an AutoResetEvent. Call event1.WaitOne() after calling BeginGetRequestStream in DoWork, and then in GetResponseCallback call event1.Set(). The background worker thread will resume.